# Stop logo image from flickering as user scrolls

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scroll, fadein, fadeout

I have two different logos and I want to smoothly fade them in and out, switching between them depending on the scrollbar's position. With the code I'm currently using, it switches between the images and applies the fading effect,  but it keeps doing it as the user keeps scrolling, giving a flicker effect as a result. Currently, I have the following code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){

     var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(true) / 3;    
     var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
 
     if(scrollTop < headerHeight){

          $('.logo').fadeOut(200, function(){

               $('.logo').attr('src','IMG_URL01').fadeIn(200);

          });   

     }else if (scrollTop > headerHeight){

          $('.logo').fadeOut(200, function(){
              $('.logo').attr('src','IMG_URL02').fadeIn(200);
         
          });
};
```

Based on the code's structure, I can see why it's giving that flicker effect; The if statement is being applied each time the user scrolls, depending on the scrollbar's position. However, I just don't know what to write and where to write it to apply the if statement only once.

Comment: check against image src for example if its `IMG_URL02` do nothing if not then do the fade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a boolean flag as each process executes, so that the boolean must be false before it executes and becomes true as it executes, then you can check for that as well in the if statement forcing it to only fire once in the scroll range.

Each process resets the other process's boolean so the other one can be initiated again when the user goes back into that scroll range again.

```
var img1IsFadedIn = false;
var img2IsFadedIn = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){

    var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(true) / 3;    
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(scrollTop < headerHeight && img1IsFadedIn == false){
        img1IsFadedIn = true;
        img2IsFadedIn = false;
        $('.logo').fadeOut(200, function(){
            $('.logo').attr('src','IMG_URL01').fadeIn(200);
        });   

    }else if (scrollTop > headerHeight && img2IsFadedIn == false){
        img2IsFadedIn = true;
        img1IsFadedIn = false;
        $('.logo').fadeOut(200, function(){
            $('.logo').attr('src','IMG_URL02').fadeIn(200);
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks! It works with just one small tweak...

When the page initially loads, IMG_URL01 still flickers, but only once. I had to add a conditional statement to see img1IsFaded as true outside of the function in order to stop that flicker for that initial scroll.